# How to copy an image from phone gallery to project

Tags: android

I need to manage dynamic pictures for users profile. Pictures will be created or deleted in runtime by users. Where should I locate this pictures (drawable folder, specific folder...)?

If you think the best way is to use a specific folder, how could I get an image from this folder to be displayed it in an ImageView. I know how to do it from drawable folder, but I do not know how to do it from a specific folder.

Finally, users will select pictures from phone gallery in runtime. I want to copy this picture from phone gallery to a folder (drawable or specific) for future use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the above.  They should be located on the SD card, which is right where the camera will put them.  When the user selects an image via the gallery or takes one via the camera from your app, you'll get a URI for the file.  Save the URI somewhere and use that to display it later.